# Label text not updating after tkFileDialog.askdirectory() || Python

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to ask for a directory and put the path on a Label, here's my code:

```
from Tkinter import *
import tkFileDialog, os

def demana_directori():
    global items, directori
    directori=tkFileDialog.askdirectory(title='Escolleix directori')
    imdr.configure(textvariable=directori)
    items=os.listdir(directori)
    for item in items:
        llista1.insert(END,item)
    llista1.insert(END,"1")
    llista2.insert(END,"2")


##MAIN
finestra=Tk()
finestra.title("Creació del Fitxer Comprimit")
finestra.minsize('0','0')


f=Frame(finestra)
f.pack()

esq=Frame(finestra)
drt=Frame(finestra)

esqtp=Frame(esq)
esq.pack(side=LEFT,fill=BOTH)
esqtp.pack(side=TOP,fill=X)

esqtp1=Frame(esqtp)
esqtp2=Frame(esqtp)

directori=StringVar()
items=['']

dr=Button(esqtp1,text='Escollir directori treball',command=demana_directori)
dr.pack(side=LEFT)
imdr=Label(esqtp1,width=30,relief=SUNKEN,textvariable=directori)
imdr.pack(side=LEFT,fill=X)
finestra.mainloop()
```

The core problem is when i press the dr Button calls the demana_directori() function and does all of it's content right, but when it finishes seems like won't run the code above the button, resulting on the label not updating, or if I put a print('Hello') after the Button won't work either.

Sorry for my poor english.

Thanks

Comment: Your code does nothing but display an empty window - there's no button or label. Furthermore, the variables `llista1` and `llista2` referenced in `demana_directori()` are undefined. Please edit your question and post a runnable example illustrating the problem.

Comment: I didn't want to put all the code since it's large, you're right, I forgot to put the declarations of the lists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When working with a `StingVar()` you need to call the method `set()` to change its value:

```
from Tkinter import *
import tkFileDialog, os

def demana_directori():
    global items, directori
    d = tkFileDialog.askdirectory(title='Escolleix directori')
    directori.set(d)

##MAIN
finestra=Tk()
finestra.title("cc")
finestra.minsize('0','0')


f=Frame(finestra)
f.pack()

esq=Frame(finestra)
drt=Frame(finestra)

esqtp=Frame(esq)
esq.pack(side=LEFT,fill=BOTH)
esqtp.pack(side=TOP,fill=X)

esqtp1=Frame(esqtp)
esqtp2=Frame(esqtp)

esqtp2.pack()
esqtp1.pack()

directori=StringVar()
items=['']

dr=Button(esqtp1,text='Escollir directori treball',command=demana_directori)
dr.pack(side=LEFT)
imdr=Label(esqtp1,width=30,relief=SUNKEN,textvariable=directori)
imdr.pack(side=LEFT,fill=X)
finestra.mainloop()
```

Comment: So much thank you!!, :D, you solved my problem, the error was that i was not doing the directori.set(d)